# wpdb query using duplicate key to check update/insert

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use the query below to insert a row into my wp_postmeta table. If this row exists already e.g the `meta_id` key is not unique I need it to update this row witht the meta_value at the end of the query.

This is what I have so far

`$wpdb->insert( 'wp_postmeta', array('post_id' => $productID[0], 'meta_key' => 'custom_field', 'meta_value' => 'worked'), array("%d","%s","%s") . " ON DUPLCIATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = changed " );`

But this is what my last query comes out as:

`string(226) "INSERT INTO`wp_postmeta`(`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) VALUES (Array ON DUPLCIATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = changed ,Array ON DUPLCIATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = changed ,Array ON DUPLCIATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = changed )"`

As you can see something in the dupolicate key is throwing this off.

Comment: @toscho the link you posted gives 404 :(

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this with wpdb object insert. Looking at the documentation:

```
$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
```

Variable *$format* has to be *Array* or *String*, if you concatenate an SQL string to your array it will cause unexpected behaviors. And you can't concatenate an Array with a String with dot.

You should rather using a raw SQL query with

```
$wdpb->query('your query')
```

Or even better:

```
$wdpb->query($wdpb->prepare('your query'))
```

to be protected from injection if values are user-inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great way to extend wdpb. I did not write this and I do not want to take credit for it. I am using this to run the 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'.

https://wpreset.com/customize-wpdb-class/